Scriptural support for trusting Scripture over private revelation
Several sects place a high premium on personal spiritual experience and/or personal revelation as a means for discovering Truth. For example: angelic visitations, miracles, dreams, visions, LDS's "burning in the bosom".
Others (likely Sola Scriptura believers in particular) would say that these experiences can be demonic in origin and are not trustworthy. In particular, they might argue that common beliefs of such sects are untrue and dangerous because they contradict Scripture (e.g. a Christian confronted by an alleged supernatural experience of a Muslim would likely assert said experience to be demonic in nature on the basis of Scripture contradicting the Qur'an).
What Scripture passages exist (if any) in support of the idea that "spiritual" experiences can be misleading? Relatedly, which verses speak to the necessity of reading Scripture rather than relying entirely on spiritual experiences and/or private revelation?

This question is about an implication of sola scriptura and I think it is very clear. We definitely do not need any comments disagreeing with sola scriptura.

2 Peter 1:16–21 is a good start. Real prophets report their visions etc. without personal comment about what they think the meaning is.

Here is an exhaustive list of all major Christian denominations (let's go with 1 MM + adherents) that believe in relying entirely on spiritual experiences and/or private revelation:                                               ___,                                                                             ___,                                                                        ___,                                                                        ___                                                                        

If you have to misrepresent someone's position in order to criticize it, this does not reflect well on your argument.

Not sure why such an important question would have a couple close votes? If necessary it could possibly be simplified to ask without the reference to all those who may put experience above scripture. It is sometimes considered insulting to put light on a topic. No doubt the scripture is the one and only light to shine the gospel into our hearts, to give us the experience of God through a justifying faith of which is its central declaration. No doubt this is without any mediator aside from the Lord Christ, the living word, also presented at its centre. Great question!

I would like additional references of sects/denominations that support revelation over scripture. You make a claim/basis for your question but don't support this beyond your interpretation

@depperm, somewhat along the lines of Mike's comment, the point isn't to call out who believes what. I made an exception for LDS because "burning in the bosom" is a recognizable and succinct example. IIUC, however, there are other sects that have similar beliefs, i.e. that the Holy Spirit will reveal in some manner the "correctness" of that sect. I'd be open to suggestions how to (succinctly) express the idea without naming a particular sect, however.

@HoldToTheRod, you can think whatever you want, but reality is that some sects believe things, often on the basis of late revelation and/or personal experiences, that other Christians believe are contrary to Scripture. In any case, while there was a specific individual that is "responsible" for this question, IIUC that person is not LDS. Nor, if you were to ask me to enumerate sects I believe are guilty of this (but let's not, please), would that list have only one item. Since you seem to have incorrectly taken this personally, your claim of misrepresentation is suspect.

@HoldToTheRod, ah, I did mention LDS twice, however. I changed the second to pick on Islam, instead. Hope that helps. If you know another sect that places high priority on a similar sort of spiritual experience, please feel free to suggest that change also. (See also my reply to depperm.)

@Matthew thanks for the clarification. Perhaps prioritizing scripture over spiritual experiences and/or private revelation would convey the idea more clearly than relying entirely spiritual experiences and/or private revelation.

The scriptures are Christ-centric and place their authority above all human experiences and above all church offices and traditions. The scriptures are: simple, clear, self-evidencing and a self-interpreting power by the Holy Spirit of the simple gospel message of Christ. This simple message of Jesus the Christ, fully God, fully man, sent by the Father, born of a virgin by the Holy Spirit, crucified for our sins and raised for our justification, in order that we might be saved by faith, simply by believing in it. True salvation is meant to be 'personally experienced' by the illumination of the Holy Spirit of the scripture but due to its objective simplicity, it can never be an exclusive private revelation. It is shared by all believers and without love of those believers our faith is a lie.
It may seem simple an obvious but the fact that we believe the scripture to be God’s word it must be above the words of anyone else, which includes experience because our experiences are when our emotions or spiritual life are affected by what we believe.  These beliefs must be tested by some authority and that authority is what God has to say about it:

The Holy Bible: English Standard Version (2 Ti 3:16–17). (2016).
Crossway Bibles.
16 All Scripture is breathed out by God and profitable for teaching,
for reproof, for correction, and for training in righteousness, 17
that the man of God may be complete, equipped for every good work.

The authors of scripture were declaring self interpreting ‘words of God’, not their own ideas:
2 Peter 1:20–21 (ESV):

20 knowing this first of all, that no prophecy of Scripture comes from
someone’s own interpretation. 21 For no prophecy was ever produced by
the will of man, but men spoke from God as they were carried along by
the Holy Spirit.

However lets not forget the scriptures are not something just giving random authoritative facts but they all have meaning only in reference to how they declare the gospel of Christ:

The Holy Bible: English Standard Version (Jn 5:39–40). (2016).
Crossway Bibles.
39 You search the Scriptures because you think that in them you have
eternal life; and it is they that bear witness about me, 40 yet you
refuse to come to me that you may have life.

This simple message of scripture does create an experience subject to its authority by the Holy Spirit revealing its truth to our hearts:

The Holy Bible: English Standard Version (1 Jn 2:20–22). (2016).
Crossway Bibles.
20 But you have been anointed by the Holy One, and you all have
knowledge. 21 I write to you, not because you do not know the truth,
but because you know it, and because no lie is of the truth. 22 Who is
the liar but he who denies that Jesus is the Christ? This is the
antichrist, he who denies the Father and the Son
The Holy Bible: English Standard Version (2 Co 4:6). (2016). Crossway
Bibles.
6 For God, who said, “Let light shine out of darkness,” has shone in
our hearts to give the light of the knowledge of the glory of God in
the face of Jesus Christ.

This knowledge in the gospel so revealed to us personally creates an experience of love founded upon knowledge of the simple gospel:

The Holy Bible: English Standard Version (1 Jn 4:7). (2016). Crossway
Bibles.
7 Beloved, let us love one another, for love is from God, and whoever
loves has been born of God and knows God.

One can’t fully separate experience from church office and tradition that is some measure is the established experience and values of a historical group. We have our own experiences, but we also live in a community that communicates those experiences into a form of agreed true and false category of experiences.   After the primitive church that taught in Christ alone as the means for salvation, something that broke with the traditions of the Rabbis, the church gradually fell back into a belief of the authority of traditions almost, or equal to scripture.  Martin Luther and others gradually helped restore the concept of the authority of scriptures back because they clearly proved from scripture that the churches' beliefs were on many points in contradiction to the scripture. Especially wicked was the belief that Rome denied the concept of an 'external justification' to a 'sinner without any good'. The common phrase is justified apart from works. They denied that justification is possible without one’s own experience of holiness be included. The reformers simply viewed this as heresy, mixing works and grace and so denying Christ, making the Pope an antichrist.
In addition to this, it is clear that the Apostle’s themselves were excluded from having any authority if they preached anything other than faith in Christ alone. This means faith in Peter, Pope or Church is not necessary for full salvation. Neither is faith in any special sects’ leaders. The Pope and all other authorities, even an Angel, can be damned to hell, if they veer off from justification in Christ alone according to Paul:

The Holy Bible: English Standard Version (Ga 1:8–9). (2016). Crossway
Bibles.
8 But even if we or an angel from heaven should preach to you a gospel
contrary to the one we preached to you, let him be accursed. 9 As we
have said before, so now I say again: If anyone is preaching to you a
gospel contrary to the one you received, let him be accursed.

For all those sects that followed the Protestant reformation and then tried to set themselves up as the ‘true church’, denying the faith of simple believers everywhere in the world. They also tend to prop up some special person with some special experience around that person, other than Christ alone, as presented in the gospel. True believers will let all these special sects and their idols be condemned, if authority of scripture is to be maintained.
To capture the attitude of Martin Luther himself on the clarity and self-interpreting and simplicity of scripture and its subsequent authority over all mankind, read his words directly:

Luther, M. (1999). Luther’s works, vol. 33: Career of the Reformer III
(J. J. Pelikan, H. C. Oswald, & H. T. Lehmann, Eds.; Vol. 33, p. 28).
Fortress Press.
I admit, of course, that there are many texts in the Scriptures that
are obscure and abstruse, not because of the majesty of their subject
matter, but because of our ignorance of their vocabulary and grammar;
but these texts in no way hinder a knowledge of all the subject matter
of Scripture. For what still sublimer thing can remain hidden in the
Scriptures, now that the seals have been broken, the stone rolled from
the door of the sepulcher [Matt. 27:66; 28:2], and the supreme mystery
brought to light, namely, that Christ the Son of God has been made
man, that God is three and one, that Christ has suffered for us and is
to reign eternally? Are not these things known and sung even in the
highways and byways? Take Christ out of the Scriptures, and what will
you find left in them?

Now regarding the misleading experiences in particular that might deviate from knowing the gospel by faith alone in Christ, there are a two main varieties. First one can have **an experience of 'zeal' in opposing the gospel according to false biblical works and tradition:

The Holy Bible: English Standard Version (Ro 10:2–4). (2016). Crossway
Bibles.
2 For I bear them witness that they have a zeal for God, but not
according to knowledge. 3 For, being ignorant of the righteousness of
God, and seeking to establish their own, they did not submit to God’s
righteousness. 4 For Christ is the end of the law for righteousness to
everyone who believes.

There is also a sensual experience that those unable to see the simple gospel, conjure up for themselves their own gospel and become excited about biblical things according to the flesh and human emotions. These find interest in scripture and bible communities in things not related to their personal cleansed conscience by faith in Christ but based on other fleshly excitements and reasons under many variations not centered on the gospel:

The Holy Bible: English Standard Version (2 Pe 2:10–22). (2016).
Crossway Bibles.
Bold and willful, they do not tremble as they blaspheme the glorious
ones, 11 whereas angels, though greater in might and power, do not
pronounce a blasphemous judgment against them before the Lord. 12 But
these, like irrational animals, creatures of instinct, born to be
caught and destroyed, blaspheming about matters of which they are
ignorant, will also be destroyed in their destruction, 13 suffering
wrong as the wage for their wrongdoing. They count it pleasure to
revel in the daytime. They are blots and blemishes, reveling in their
deceptions, while they feast with you. 14 They have eyes full of
adultery, insatiable for sin. They entice unsteady souls. They have
hearts trained in greed. Accursed children! 15 Forsaking the right
way, they have gone astray. They have followed the way of Balaam, the
son of Beor, who loved gain from wrongdoing, 16 but was rebuked for
his own transgression; a speechless donkey spoke with human voice and
restrained the prophet’s madness.  17 These are waterless springs and
mists driven by a storm. For them the gloom of utter darkness has been
reserved. 18 For, speaking loud boasts of folly, they entice by
sensual passions of the flesh those who are barely escaping from those
who live in error. 19 They promise them freedom, but they themselves
are slaves of corruption. For whatever overcomes a person, to that he
is enslaved. 20 For if, after they have escaped the defilements of the
world through the knowledge of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ, they
are again entangled in them and overcome, the last state has become
worse for them than the first. 21 For it would have been better for
them never to have known the way of righteousness than after knowing
it to turn back from the holy commandment delivered to them. 22 What
the true proverb says has happened to them: “The dog returns to its
own vomit, and the sow, after washing herself, returns to wallow in
the mire.”

These are broad stoke false experiences.  Either inserting some of our own experience of works to save us, or the religious sensual experiences of those without the Holy Spirit and without a new birth. Subjecting our experience to the simple truth of the gospel makes us a Christian, otherwise our faith is a lie and our experiences our death.

I would suggest that Acts 8:30-33 speaks about not understanding scripture without a guide. If even scripture needs a guide, how much more other spiritual experiences?
An Ethiopian asks Philip to interpret the scriptures for him. He even says - How can I understand it unless someone explains it to me. Now, some might say that this only applies to difficult prophecy texts like Isaiah 53, however, I argue that any scripture can be difficult to work out. A second argument against this argument might be that the Holy Spirit can be the person to explain scripture to me, however, in my personal life, I haven't found that to work all the time, that is, sometimes I need humans to help me.
Acts 8:30-33

30 Then Philip ran up to the chariot and heard the man reading Isaiah the prophet. “Do you understand what you are reading?” Philip asked. 31 “How can I,” he said, “unless someone explains it to me?” So he invited Philip to come up and sit with him. 32 This is the passage of Scripture the eunuch was reading:


Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.
